# Where to request a female cover?

Tags: sound, production-mixing

I am trying to remake a song, I'm just missing the female voice.

Is there any site where I vn request for a female cover?

[remaking](/questions/tagged/remaking)

Answer (score 0):

Try Craiglist. There you can find vocalists or musicians around you. Also there are a lot of Facebook groups concerning musicians around your area.

Answer (score 0):

StarNow.co.uk has a lot of singers.